# Is there a hack to push comments but not code?

Tags: git

My colleagues and I are exploring a new codebase that significantly lacks documentation. We're adding documentation as we step through the code base. At the same time, we're implementing some small features. I want to repeatedly **merge in only the comments that my team members have added to their development branch but not any changes to the code itself. Is there a way to do this?**

A potential solution is: for each developer A through D, ask each developer to maintain two branches (for example, A1 and A2). A1 will only contain comments that the developers added; A2 will include both comments and any actual code changes. The problem with this approach is that it requires that my colleagues and I be disciplined. That we only add documentation in branch A1 and, if we need to edit the actual code, first switch into A2.

Comment: It *would* be possible to prevent pushes with a hook, but that is only as good as your code / parser to test for only comment changes. A well understood process with pull requests and required review/approval is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it could be:

1. Have separate atomic commits for your comments: Don't mix comments with code in the same commit
2. Cherry-pick commits with comments in your target branch

```
   git log branch-with-commits-and-comments
   git checkout target-branch
   git cherry-pick hash1 hash2 hash3
```